# Change Global isolation level in google clould SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I need to change the isolation level in the google cloud SQL , I searched a lot , but could not find it any where When i did

SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

It gets changed , but only for that session and not for global , ie all other subsequent are not changed.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah -can't believe this is not part of the MySQL flags in the config.

Comment: Same here - any hint where we can vote for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISOLATION LEVEL is reset every time an instance warms up . so the only option now is to set it every time you create a connection

Comment: This answer is outdated

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that it can be done now

[image]

its also listed on their [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags)

Comment: This answer should be accepted